# Text color of selected button android

Tags: android, button, textcolor

I have a button like so:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textColor="@color/my_gray" />
```

After pressing the button, the text color turns a darker gray color (a "this has already been pressed" color).  How do I prevent this?  On the button press I do `button.setTextColor(R.color.my_gray);` to reset the color, but it has no effect.

Comment: Are you doing some kind of heavy-lifting in the UI thread after the button is pressed that is preventing it from returning to it's normal state?

Comment: I'm just setting a view to visible when the button is pressed.

Comment: Strange, and the button is still staying in the pressed state?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the pressed state.  It seems like a "you already pushed me" state, like how a link turns a different color after it has been clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a different kind of button. [CompoundButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html) or [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) might work out for you since you can control their backgrounds/images more easily.

However, the best way to do it might be to use a selector like [this guide](http://adnan.chohdry.com/android-button-image-pressed-effect/) shows.

Comment: I think I was essentially trying to replicate a compound button, but a little different, so I'll mark this as correct.